# Where am I wrong in determining Parallel vs Perpendicular?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am quoting Mathematics for Economists by Simon and Blume (page 347, Theorem 15.5) here.

> The vector $\mathbf{v}=(v_1,v_2)$ points in the direction parallel to the tangent line to the level set of $G$ at $(x_0,y_0)$ if and only if $$DG(x_0,y_0)\cdot\mathbf{v}=\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)v_1+\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)v_2=0,$$ where $DG(x_0,y_0)=(\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0),\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0))$.

But, if we take $$\mathbf{v}=\left(1,-\frac{\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)}{\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)}\right),$$ $DG(x_0,y_0)\cdot\mathbf{v}=0$, but $DG(x_0,y_0)$ and $\mathbf{v}$ are perpendicular!

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradient $DG$ is perpendicular to the tangent line $T$. Since you are working in the plane statement from the book is perfectly correct:

$$ v \perp DG \iff v \parallel T. $$

PS: Recall that $v\cdot w = 0 \iff v\perp w$.

Comment: You mean that I am correct and the book is wrong? That is, a typo there?

Comment: I mean the book is correct and you're also correct. I don't see the problem to be honest, everything makes perfect sense